# What is the maximum y-value of the following function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the maximum y-value of the following function?

$$y=8t - \frac{t^2}{2} -24 $$

It can be done by using the parabolic equation , setting the equation is equal zero. But is there any other straight forward or  shortest method to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [complete the square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square):

$$y=-\frac{1}{2}(t^2-16t+48)=-\frac{1}{2}((t-8)^2-16)=-\frac{1}{2}(t-8)^2+8$$

Since $-\dfrac{1}{2}(t-8)^2\le0$ for every $t$, the maximum occurs of $y$ when this expression is $0$ (which is at $t=8$). This gives the maximum of $y$ as $0+8=8$.

Comment: @mathlove already did that

Comment: @Aditya [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8191/about-posting-identical-answers-to-a-question) discussion on the math meta may be of interest to you. Additionally mathlove's answer seems to no longer appear.

Answer (score 2):

for the form of $y = ax^2 + bx + c$ the min (or max) is :

$$y=c-\frac{b^2}{4a}$$

which in this case is :

$$-24+32=8$$

Comment: Is there a name for this theorem? Maybe a proof? I've never seen this before.

Comment: just find the min/max parametrically and substitute in the equation (again parametrically)

Comment: I solved it after asking the question :). Did it using Aditya's answer, but keeping it general.

Comment: @Cruncher there's no theorem for this, per se.  This fact can be derived by completing the square as described by Peter above, or by using calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Using calculus:
$$y'=8-t$$ 
Using derivative test $8-t=0\implies t=8$
So,$$y_{\text{extremum}}=64-32-24=8$$
Second derivate:
$$y''=-1<0$$
So extremum is a maximum.

Comment: why the downvote

Answer (score 0):

$$y(t)=8t-\frac{t^2}{2}-24$$

$$y'(t)=0 \Rightarrow 8-t=0 \Rightarrow t=8$$

For $t>8:$ $y>0$

For $t<8:$ $y<0$

So, $y$ is decreasing on $(-\infty, 0]$ and increasing on $[0,+\infty)$.

Therefore, $y$ achieves its minimum at $t=8$, which is equal to $y(8)=8$.